# PHP Include not working with bootstrap dropdown's

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

(Bootstrap 3)
If I did

http://dev.artsicleprojects.com/navbar.php

the dropdowns function, however if I do

http://dev.artsicleprojects.com/index.php

The dropdowns do nothing.
My index.php code is right here

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Artsicle Projects Dev</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <?php include 'navbar.php'?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

Code for navbar.php:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.css"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>Artsicle Projects</h1>
</div>
<div class="dropdown" style="position: absolute; left: 30%">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Games

        <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="catclicker/index.php">Cat Clicker</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Exit The Room</a></li>
        <li><a href="comingsoon/index.html">Coming Soon!</h5></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown" style="position: absolute; left: 60%">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Extra

        <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Nothing</a></li>
        <li><a href="comingsoon/index.html">Coming Soon!</h5></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have invalid markup in your `index.php` by having multiple `<head>`, `<body>`, `<script>` etc. This is because `navbar.php` is a complete (standalone) HTML page and you're include that complete page into another page. View the source of each page and you'll see what's happening.

Remove everything from `navbar.php` that isn't inside `<body>`. That is, only include the markup for the navbar, not `<head>`, `<body>`, `<script>` etc. that's in `navbar.php`.

Comment: Oh, fixed it. Didn't read the <script> part. Upvoted and answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct order.
Move header section from navbar.php to header:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Artsicle Projects Dev</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.artsicleprojects.com/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.artsicleprojects.com/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dev.artsicleprojects.com/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>Artsicle Projects</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" style="position: absolute; left: 30%">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Games

            <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="catclicker/index.php">Cat Clicker</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Exit The Room</a></li>
            <li><a href="comingsoon/index.html">Coming Soon!</h5></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown" style="position: absolute; left: 60%">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Extra

            <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Nothing</a></li>
            <li><a href="comingsoon/index.html">Coming Soon!</h5></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div></body>
</html>
```